# How to change/replace index values dyanmically in list using java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i want to change the values in list

Actually output:
"summary": [
{
valuesa:"1",
titlecount:"20"
}
]

Required one:
"summary": [
{
Values A:"1",
Title Count:"20"
}
]

need to change the text by adding caps letter and space in required area.

Comment: What is the criterion to split the text and capitalize the letter? Also, this seems to be a map within a list. Can you please add some Java code which produces this? That will help the helpers. :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like this (assuming the List is of string arrays):

```
// Create List...
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new String[] {"valuesa:\"1\"", "titlecount:\"10\""});
list.add(new String[] {"valuesb:\"2\"", "titlecount:\"20\""});
list.add(new String[] {"valuesc:\"3\"", "titlecount:\"30\""});
    
// Convert List...
for (String[] str : list) {
    str[0] = str[0].toUpperCase().replace("VALUES", "Values ");
    str[1] = str[1].replace("titlecount", "Title Count");
}
    
// Display List...
for (String[] str : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
}
```

When run the output to the Console Window will be:

```
[Values A:"1", Title Count:"10"]
[Values B:"2", Title Count:"20"]
[Values C:"3", Title Count:"30"]
```